# usar un Where cuando se tiene una condicion

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que estoy tratando de realizar es que se lleve a cabo una búsqueda en la base de datos mediante una condición ya definida, y que a su vez se aplique solo a los que tengan $cargo igual, pero no la realiza solo dice que hay un error en la sintaxis

En esta primera parte es donde se encuentra la parte de control del donde capturo los datos buscarPor y dato, que son los necesarios para la condición y a su vez agregó una nueva variable llamada $cargo para aplicar el WHERE

```
 function buscarUsuarios(Request $request){

  $modelo = new ClienteModel();
  $cargo = 16;
  $buscarPor = (int) $request->input("buscarPor");
  $dato = strtolower($request->input("dato"));
  $usuarios = $modelo->buscarUsuario($buscarPor, $dato, $cargo);     


  if(!empty($usuarios)){

    $response = array("response" => true, "usuarios" => $usuarios);

  }else{

    $response = array("response" => false, "message" => "No se encontraron resultados");

  }


  return $response;

}
```

Aquí es donde se lleva a cabo la sentencia SQL, como se puede observar tengo una condición y a la vez que sea solo donde el id_cargo sea igual que el $cargo

```
 function buscarUsuarios($opcionBusqueda, $dato, $cargo){

  switch ((int) $opcionBusqueda) {
    case 1:
      $condicion = "WHERE u.codigo LIKE '%".$dato."%'";
      break;
    case 2:
        $condicion = "WHERE u.cedula LIKE '%".$dato."%'";
        break;
    case 3:
        $condicion = "WHERE (u.nombre_1 LIKE '%".$dato."%' OR u.nombre_2 LIKE '%".$dato."%')";
        break;
    case 4:
        $condicion = "WHERE (u.apellido_1 LIKE '%".$dato."%' OR u.apellido_2 LIKE '%".$dato."%')";
        break;
    default:
      $condicion = "WHERE u.codigo LIKE %'".$dato."'%";
      break;
  }

  $usuarios = DB::select('SELECT u.id,
                                 u.codigo,
                                 u.avatar,
                                 u.cedula,
                                 u.id_cargo,
                                 CONCAT(u.nombre_1," ",u.nombre_2," ",u.apellido_1," ",u.apellido_2) AS nombre,
                                 e.descripcion AS estatus,
                                 cu.correo_principal
                         FROM tbl_usuario u,
                              tbl_estatus e,
                              tbl_contacto_usuario cu
                              where u.id_cargo = '.$cargo.'
                         '.$condicion.'
                         AND e.tabla = "tbl_usuario"
                         AND e.valor = u.id_estatus
                         AND u.id = cu.id_usuario');
  if(count($usuario) > 0){

    return $usuarios;

  }else{

    return array();

  }

}
```

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Estas escribiendo `where` dos veces: en el cargo y en la `$condicion`

Comment: message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE u.codigo LIKE '%1%'
↵

Comment: como que lo estoy escribiendo dos veces whrere

Comment: `where u.id_cargo = '.$cargo.'` y `$condicion = "WHERE u.codigo LIKE '%".$dato."%'";`

Comment: ok, entiendo dejame revisar

Comment: Como ha señalado @alanfcm, debes empezar cada `$condicion` por  ` AND ` (nótese que hay un espacio en blanco antes) no por `WHERE`, porque ya tienes un `where` fijo en la consulta. Y, para que tu código sea saludable a la vista, puedes escribir las variables así: `$condicion = "WHERE (u.nombre_1 LIKE '%$dato%' OR u.nombre_2 LIKE '%$dato%')";`

Answer (score 1):

Estas escribiendo

```
      $condicion = "WHERE u.codigo LIKE %'".$dato."'%";
```

Para construir una condición que luego será usada en tu consulta , pero

```
   where u.id_cargo = '.$cargo.'
                     '.$condicion.'
```

en tu consulta ya tienes una condición WHERE y luego en la variable string $condicion viene otro WHERE por lo tanto la consulta tiene error de sintaxis.